# "Too few arguments to function sisventas\Http\Controllers\CategoriaController::edit(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected"

Tags: php, laravel, base-de-datos

una vez que he solucionado el inconveniente en el create ya puedo cargar los datos en la base de datos. Ahora cuando quiero actualizar la categoria me sale el siguiente error:
"Too few arguments to function sisventas\Http\Controllers\CategoriaController::edit(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected"

es como si no estuviera trayendo los datos de la categoria que deseo, los codigos son los siguientes en controller que es donde me salta el error:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    return view("almacen.categoria.edit",["categoria"=>Categoria::findOrFail($id)]);
}

public function update(CategoriaFormRequest $REQUEST,$id)
{
    $categoria=Categoria::findOrFail($id);
    $categoria->nombre=$REQUEST->get('nombre');
    $categoria->descripcion=$REQUEST->get('descripcion');
    $categoria->update();
    return redirect::to('almacen/categoria');

}
```

les dejo el codigo del formulario..

```
<form action=" {{route('form.edit')}}" method="post">
@method('patch')
@csrf


<div class="form-group">
<label for="nombre">Nombre Categoria</label>
<input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" value="{{ $categoria ->nombre}}">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="nombre">Descripcion Categoria</label>
<input type="text" name="descripcion" class="form-control" value="{{ $categoria ->descripcion}}">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Actualizar</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger" type="reset"> Cancelar</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer no estas enviando ningún dato, probablemente no estes asignando el correcto id, solo para corroborar puedes intentar ver lo que envias en tu función edit con un dd antes del return de esta forma:

```
$categoria=Categoria::findOrFail($id);
dd($categoria);
```

Otra sugerencia que te puedo dar en función update es que no recibas solo el id sino toda la categoria

```
public function update(CategoriaFormRequest $REQUEST,Categoria $categoria)
{
    $categoria->nombre=$REQUEST->get('nombre');
    $categoria->descripcion=$REQUEST->get('descripcion');
    $categoria->update();
    return redirect::to('almacen/categoria');

}
```

Espero te sea útil.

Comment: Hola Fresia, he colocado el codigo que me has pasado: $categoria=Categoria::findOrFail($id);
dd($categoria); y me sigue saltando el mismo error

Comment: Probablemente en tu ruta no estes enviando el dato correctamente, por ejemplo tu ruta prodia ser de esta manera: Route::get('categoria_edit/{id}/edit','CategoriaController@edit');

Comment: O muestrame cual es tu ruta